# How to rollback data.sql script in integration tests?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-test

I came across this problem:

For out integration tests, we have an older database with already populated data. Some data don't have the right values (for example, for a boolean column, there is also null value). Now, when creating some integration tests, these ones are failing due to data not having correct values.

What I thought it would be a good idea was to have some scripts in the `data.sql` file that corrects the data (for example `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = 0 WHERE my_column IS NULL`) But the problem is that this update also commits to the database and thus the data is changed (now there are no more `null` values). Changing the database data in not an option, so what I'm trying to do is some sort of a rollback of the `data.sql` file at the end of each test / class. Can you please adivse?

The version is `Spring boot 2.0.7.RELEASE`, the depedency for testing is `spring-boot-starter-test`, the tests are annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and the database is `Oracle`.

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: ${URL}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}
    continue-on-error: true
```

Comment: I would advise using test containers instead, a db container that will run in docker every time that execute your tests, and the schema will get created similar to the one in production once the test is completed the container shutdowns.

Comment: I would also advise against relying on rollbacks for this. Work with a new schema you can write to and throw away or truncate and restart each time.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use Oracle's [flashback table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-TABLE.html#GUID-FA9AF2FD-2DAD-4387-9E62-14AFC26EA85C) feature to rollback all DML changes that happened since `data.sql` was ran. I'm not sure how Spring Boot testing works, but I assume there is some way to call a pre- and post- actions that can call the below Oracle commands.

First, you will likely need to enable row movement on the relevant tables. This step is only needed once for each table and cannot be undone. (But the change is also pretty harmless. If I recall correctly, the only downside is a very tiny increase in metadata space.)

```
alter table my_table1 enable row movement;
alter table my_table2 enable row movement;
```

Right before the test begins, create a uniquely named restore point that is used to record the exact system change number to roll back to.

```
create restore point restore_point_1;
```

The run `data.sql` and all other testing changes.

When testing is done, run a `FLASHBACK TABLE` command that will restore all of the relevant tables back to their state as of the restore point.

```
flashback table my_table1, my_table2 to restore point restore_point_1;
```

As commenters have suggested, there are cleaner, more modern ways to instantly recreate data. But not everybody has containers or build scripts setup. I've seen this flashback approach used successfully by testers with only a small amount of effort.

There are some potential gotchas when using flashback. The restore point and changed data will only last so long. If your tests will go on for days, you may need to look into guaranteed restore points and adjusting your database's UNDO tablespace. Flashback table only works on DML, and will not work if a table is altered, and will not restore things like stored procedures or sequence values. If you need *everything* flashed back, then you might be able to use flashback database, but that command also has some complications.